# Flutter: Different dependency versions for different platforms?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Is it possible in pubspec.yaml to have different dependency versions depending on the platform?

I have an application where i need a different dependency for the Web platform, or is that just a bad idea in general?

Comment: Can you share the issue which made you do so?

Comment: There is currently a bug on the cloud_firestore package which stops transactions running on Android: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1969. I can roll back the version to fix it but the older version doesn't support web. Was looking for a workaround but it looks like there is none.

Comment: did you find any workaround for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible